# Explicitly releasing Mat with opencv 2.0

Tags: android, performance, memory-management, opencv, android-ndk

I'm working on a program where we do some image processing of full quality camera photos using the Android NDK. So, obviously memory usage is a big concern.

There are times where I don't need the contents of a Mat anymore - I know that it'll be released automatically when it goes out of scope, but is there a good way of releasing it earlier, so I can reduce the memory usage?

It's running fine on my Galaxy S II right now, but obviously that is not representative of the capabilities of a lot of the older phones around!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have only one matrix pointing to your data, you can do this trick:

```
Mat img = imread("myImage.jpg");
// do some operations
img = Mat(); // release it
```

If more than one Mat is pointing to your data, what you should do is to release all of them

```
Mat img = imread("myImage.jpg");

Mat img2 = img;
Mat roi = img(Rect(0,0,10,10));
// do some operations

img = Mat(); // release all of them
img2 = Mat();
roi = Mat();
```

Or use the bulldozer approach: (Are you sure? this sounds like inserting bugs in your code )

```
Mat img = imread("myImage.jpg");

Mat img2 = img;
Mat roi = img(Rect(0,0,10,10));
// do some operations
char* imgData = (char*)img.data;

free[] imgData;

imshow("Look, this is called access violation exception", roi);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have yet to give this a try but it seems like a good approach!

Comment: Are the first two different than replacing each "foo = Mat();" with "foo.release();"?  I would cry to see code doing the third one.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

Mat::release() should do the trick.

cf.: [OpenCV Memory Management Documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/memory_management.html)

Comment: Mat.release() just decrement the reference counter. It releases the memory only when counter is zero.

Comment: Isn't that, in effect, what the chosen solution does where an empty Mat() is assigned to each variable with a reference to the data?